# AddEventListener doesn't trigger the function on mouseover

Tags: javascript, php, html

I'm trying to generate a set of radio buttons, each with their own AddEventListener, but I can't get it to work, using the following code (this is in a while loop using data from a MySQLI table):

```
echo '
  <script>
    document.getElementById("' . $row['colID'] . '").addEventListener("mouseover", function() {findSpec("' . $row['colID'] . '")});
  </script>';

echo '<input type="radio" id="' . $row['colID'] . '" name="colours" value="" />' . $row['colRef'] . ' ' . $row['colName'];
```

It's producing the following HTML

```
<script>
  document.getElementById("129").addEventListener("mouseover", function() {findSpec("129")});
</script>

<input type="radio" id="129" name="colours" value="">
  Shadow Content (User Agent)= $0
</input>
R-382 Congo Blue
```

I've not used AddEventListener before, so I have no idea why it isn't working. I've tried click as well, with the same problem.

Any ideas?

Comment: An `<input />` element has no child nodes. The markup the browser will generate looks like: `<input type="radio" id="129" name="colours" value="" />Shadow Content (User Agent)= $0 R-382 Congo Blue`. And as long as the `.addEventListener()` is executed when the DOM node with the given id is already available then your script works (hover over the radio button triggers the `console.log()`) -> https://jsfiddle.net/m78kfpqs/

Comment: If you look at your developer console, you'll see an error on the addEventListener, because the script has been added before the inputs. Move the scripts to the bottom of the page.

Answer (score 0):

Try to put the script after the input within page code

If it work you can 
Add your code in

document.onload=function(){ ....your addevent.istener }
In head.script section of the document

As is (within code read) your button won’t exist in the dom at the time of addevent.listener